# Shift and Logical operation giving unexpected answer

Tags: go

```
func main() {
    var score int = 5
    var shifter int = 3

    if score&1<<shifter != 0 {
        fmt.Println(score, 1<<shifter, score&1<<shifter)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("false")
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a 5 & 8 should be 0 but instead I'm seeing 8 as the answer after bitwise AND. What am I doing wrong? AFAICT, << is operating on integer types and should give me 0.

Answer (score 4):

The operator `<<` and `&` has the same precedence, so what you are actually doing is:

```
(score&1)<<shifter
```

Looks like what you need is:

```
score&(1<<shifter)
```

Comment: `<<` and `&` have the same precedence, so it is just evaluating from left to right when you don't have parentheses.

Comment: That is the problem, thanks! I think I made a mistake of not checking the Go's language spec and instead assumed my minimal knowledge of C operator precedence here.